# Confused with this regex expression

Tags: regex, autohotkey

So I have this piece of code:

```
...
Else If (RegExMatch(hayStr, "iS)(\[[a-z0-9]*\])*"))
{
    hayStr := RegExReplace(hayStr, "S)\[[0-9]+\]*", "")
    hayStr := RegExReplace(hayStr, "iS)(\[citation needed\])*", "")
    hayStr := RegExReplace(hayStr, "iS)(\[note [0-9]+\])*", "")
}
Else
{
    hayStr := RegExReplace(hayStr, "([-\.\(\)\s]*)", "")
}
```

The first part (not shown) formats the URL in the clipboard. The second part (else if) removes citations from a Wiki entry, while the last part removes special characters and white spaces in a phone number.

The problem is, trying out the code, the first part works great, so does the second part, however, when it comes to formatting phone numbers, it doesn't seem to catch the clipboard content. I have a feeling that it gets caught in the second part instead because of [0-9]*. Shouldn't phone numbers (eg: +1 234-567-8900) be caught in the Else statement since it doesn't have brackets?

Comment: What is the value of hayStr? Make a setup where you know which code runs so that you know if you are solving the right problem. What is this talk about clipboard, it seems irrelevant. 
Showing some data would help I think.

Comment: The value of hayStr comes from the clipboard which can either be a URL string, a phone number, a paragraph from a Wiki entry with citations.

There's no strict format for the phone numbers (since it varies from source to source), and the only constant for the Wiki entry is that it may or may not have citations. There's no problem with the first condition for URLs though.

Comment: Can you add a print statement to each branch of the `If` to see which one is being executed?

Comment: I agree with Barmar. Put message boxes everywhere in your code to find out where the execution stops. `MsgBox` or `MsgBox, %hayStr%` to display the contents of hayStr.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
F4:: ; press F4 to trigger it
hayStr := Clipboard
If (RegExMatch(hayStr, "S)(\[.*\])"))
{
    hayStr := RegExReplace(hayStr, "S)\[\d+\]", "")
    hayStr := RegExReplace(hayStr, "iS)(\[citation needed\])", "")
    hayStr := RegExReplace(hayStr, "iS)(\[note \d+\])", "")
}
Else
{
    hayStr := RegExReplace(hayStr, "[-\.\(\)\s]", "")
}

MsgBox, %hayStr%
```